# Pass char* to function and overwrite it in memory

Tags: c++, buffer

I want to pass a string (char *) to a function inside a dll to overwrite it with another string.

File dll.cpp

```
__declspec(dllexport) void getString(char *name, char *buffer, int len) {

    std::string str = getString(); // buffer should be overwritten with this string
    char *cstr = new char[str.length() + 1];
    strcpy(cstr, str.c_str());
    strncpy(buffer, cstr, len);

}
```

File main.cpp

```
char *buffer;
getString("z", buffer, 128);      
printf("%s", buffer);
```

I dont know how to correctly pass the buffer to overwrite it.

Comment: what is wrong with the code? Why do you think you are passing the buffer wrong?

Comment: What memory are you overwriting?

Comment: No i want to copy std::string str into char *buffer. If i had an idea whats wrong i would try it.. of course

Comment: buffer doesn't point to any memory.

Comment: You already know with cstr. Why are you returning void?

Comment: Why do you want to use C-style-strings (`const char*`) anyway, when you could use `std::string` all the time? This would make your life much easier.

Comment: @CppNoob The answer is already in the code you have written. You correctly make `cstr` point to some memory, you just need to do the same thing with `buffer`. There's nothing wrong with the way you are passing `buffer` to `getString` the problem is that you didn't give `buffer` a value, it's an uninitialised pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty clear you're confused about pointers. It looks like your use of `cstr` is at attempt to give `buffer` some memory, but that won't work and `cstr` is unnecessary.

Here's the correct code, `buffer` is allocated in main, and `cstr` is eliminated.

```
char *buffer = new char[128];
getString("z", buffer, 128);      
printf("%s", buffer);

__declspec(dllexport) void getString(char *name, char *buffer, int len)
{
    std::string str = getString();
    strncpy(buffer, str.c_str(), len);
}
```

Note that `strncpy` is a dangerous function to use as it doesn't guarantee that the output is nul terminated. I would prefer to see code like this

```
__declspec(dllexport) void getString(char *name, char *buffer, int len)
{
    if (len == 0)
    {
        // some kind of error handling
    }
    std::string str = getString();
    strncpy(buffer, str.c_str(), len - 1);
    buffer[len - 1] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Returned buffer may not be null-terminated

Comment: @stark yes, i'm just in the process of pointing that out.